# gspread_formatting get_user_entered_format для нескольких ячеек сразу

Tags: python, google-spreadsheet

Есть Google таблица, и мне нужно получить её данные. На основе цвета в ней определяется одно из значений. Получить данные со страницы  легко -

```
gspread.service_account("some_path").open_by_key("some_key").sheet1.get_all_records()
```

Также я могу получить цвет любой ячейки по её индексу (уже с помощью библиотеки gspread_formatting -

```
gspread_formatting.get_user_entered_format(gspread.service_account("some_path").open_by_key("some_key").sheet1, "A3").backgroundColor
```

Функции, которая бы вернула цвета всех ячеек на странице или её диапазон, я не нашёл, а при циклических запросах возникает ошибка слишком частых обращений.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить все данные (в том числе и цвет) со страницы, не превышая лимит запросов на googlesheets?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, вскрыл метод get_user_entered_format, подсмотрел там как извлекаются данные и сделал свой запрос:

```
account = gspread.service_account(filename="my_key_filename.json")
sheet = account.open_by_key("my_google_sheets_id").sheet1
records = sheet.get_all_records()
response_data = sheet.spreadsheet.fetch_sheet_metadata({
    'includeGridData': True,
    'ranges': [f"{sheet.title}!A2:A{len(records) + 1}"],
    'fields': 'sheets.data.rowData.values.userEnteredFormat'
})
response_data = response_data['sheets'][0]['data'][0].get('rowData')
cells_format = [cell_format.get("values")[0].get('userEnteredFormat')
                .get('backgroundColor') if cell_format
                else {"red": 1, "green": 1, "blue": 1}
                for cell_format in response_data]
```